# How to get Country ID from Country Name in Magento1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, countries, directory

I want to get `country_id` from the country name in Magento, Please suggest how can I achieve this.
I found these database tables but they are not helpful:

- directory_country
- directory_country_region
- directory_country_region_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code for that

```
$countryName = 'your country name';
$countryId = '';
$countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
    if ($countryName == $country->getName()) {
        $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
        break;
    }
}
$countryCollection = null;
print_r($countryId);
```

Comment: I don't think that loading a full collection is the best idea in this case even if it works.

Comment: I dont know any other way ? if you know please post an answer I  also take benifit and learn something  from masters like you

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, It works for me. Thanks.

Comment: You are always Welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

The country names don't come from the database.
They come from the ZF data xmls.
You can see what this returns:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslationList();
```

Not sure about it, but it should return a list like this:

```
array(
   'AF' => 'Afghanistan', 
   'AG' => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
   ....
   'ZW' => 'Zimbabwe'
);
```

If this is true, you can just get it like this:

```
$countryName = 'your country name here';
$countries = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslationList();;
$countryCode = array_search($countryName, $countries);
```

Comment: Great way though. you are real genious

Comment: @Marius, Thanks. This is also other way to achieve this.